Adding multiple Image texture on both sides of plane
I am new to Blender and have to read a lot of thread to add multiple image texture on both sides of plane. I do this in editor nodes only and you can still edit UV for each image seperately.
I want to share my method in case anyone need
Also I want to ask is there better way to do it with less nodes




You can use an Input > Geometry (Backfacing output) to project a different image or shader on the 2 sides of the plane

Yes, thats what I use, but when adding multiple image on each side. I have to try adding the alpha of all the images. Sometimes images can make a black part on the other side so Up there is all the nodes I used. It works, I just put there so anyone might need can search. And also I want to find a better way with less nodes or bettor nodes

The best would be to prepare each page in an image editor software like Photoshop or Krita

Thank you, I think thats a way to do it !!
